# Как спрятать кнопку?

Tags: android, java

Нужно сделать кнопку из активити как пункт в опционном меню. Помогите разобраться с этим.

Comment: нечего не понял, скрыть? или сделать ее как пункт меню? в чем проблема?

Comment: сделать как пункт меню

Comment: Ну, добавляете item в menu(в xml, что это и зачем ищите по названию onCreateOptionsMenu), с названием как у вашей кнопки, а в onOptionsItemSelected для нужного id, пишете все, что выполнялось при нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 2):

Внимательно изучите [документацию](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). Если будут более конкретные вопросы - тогда спрашивайте.